# How to create multiple size variations for a WebP image in Wordpress just like PNG?

Tags: wordpress, webp

Wordpress automatically creates multiple size variations for PNG, JPEG.. images. I want to replicate the same functionality for only WebP images also and not other media uploaded into Wordpress.

I think this is possible but seems to find no solution to this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! These kind of questions are maybe better asked at [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=webp). At Stack Overflow we help at explicitly coding problems. So if you started to program something and have difficulties you may come back. Please Learn about [how to provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and have a look about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks, @Paflow. Much appreciated.